# Swift: Listen for global shortcut on specific keyboard

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, macos-carbon

Is there any way on macOS to register global shortcut on specific keyboard?

I'm writing small app for turning my second keyboard into a "macro keyboard", but cannot find any way to determine which keyboard sent a shortcut.

For example, I'd like to intercept "A" button press on the second keyboard, and don't send that key to the foreground application.